# Regex for invalid Base64 characters

Tags: regex

How to create regex which `match all invalid Base64` characters ?
I found on stack `[^a-zA-Z0-9+/=\n\r].*$` but when I try I got in result  string with `-` sign.
I don't know regex at all, can anyone validate that this is good or bad regex ?

Comment: It depends on the Base64 variant that you're trying to validate. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 for details on the different variants

Answer (score 12):

The short answer to your question is that if the message contains any match for a character from the class `[^A-Za-z0-9+/=\s]` then it contains an invalid base-64 character, except for MIME messages which may freely mix other data (for various purposes) together with the base-64 stream. (These other characters are deleted before decoding the base-64 object.)

As someone who was lucky enough to help write the internals of a very fast base 64 encoding program, that processed multi-byte blocks with each machine instruction, let me add a few remarks:

- The base-64 alphabet is: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`
- output must be padded by zero or more `=` signs as necessary so that the total length of non-whitespace characters is a multiple of four.
- Those equals signs can only occur at the end of the base-64 message, and there can be at most two of them.
- Whitespace should be ignored regardless of what type. Usually messages are wrapped to a certain margin (which must be a multiple of four), but this is not necessary. The purpose of a base 64 encoding is to transfer arbitrary values, especially binary data, as plain text. You could theoretically even read someone a JPEG image over the phone using base 64 encoding.

My suggestion therefore for validating a base-64 message is to do more than just use a regular expression. Instead,

1. Eliminate all whitespace and call the length of the resulting output `z`.
2. Count the number `x` of base-64 alphabet characters.
3. Count the number `y` of equals sign(s) at the end of the message.
4. Return valid if `y` is at most 2 and `x + y = z` and invalid otherwise.

   - Note 1: The padding characters `==` or `=` do not serve any purpose in protecting the integrity of the data, and there are many derivatives of base-64 encoding which do not use them. Many consider the padding to be almost as useless and wasteful of processing time as the CR portion of the CRLF line-ending sequence.
   - Note 2: The variant used for MIME encoding accepts characters outside the base-64 alphabet to be contained within the message stream, but simply discards them when decoding the base-64 data object.
   - Note 3: I dislike the modern term "Base64" since it is an extremely ugly word. This fake word was never used by the original base-64 writers, but was adopted sometime in the next nine years.

You can encode most of this into a regular expression as follows (without the precise length checks on the last block of base-64 data):

```
^\s*(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})+\s*)*[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}\s*$
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your graphic from??

Comment: It is a screenshot obtained by pasting my regular expression here: http://www.regexper.com I noticed someone else who took a screenshot from the same place a few weeks ago and used it in their S.O. answer, and I tracked down the website with some Google searching because it was cool!

Comment: I used [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/) it looks essentially the same. I think the graphic looks better in yours though.

Answer (score 2):

That should probably be `^[a-zA-Z0-9+/\r\n]+={0,2}$`<sup>1</sup> instead.

Currently it only matches one valid character then allows anything after it. So, for instance:

```
aGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==     match
aGV%sb-G8sIHdvcmxkIQ==   also a match (starts with "a")
```

Whereas removing `.*` at the end, and adding a quantifier to the class, it forces the entire string to be legit:

```
aGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==     match
aGV%sb-G8sIHdvcmxkIQ==   not a match
```

<sup>1</sup> As @p.s.w.g pointed out, a valid base64 shouldn't contain `=` *within* the value (since `=` has special meaning and is used as a filler).

Comment: `=====` isn't a valid base64 sequence either. What about `^[a-zA-Z0-9+/\n\r]+={0,2}$`?

Comment: Does this take into account that the end must contain from 0 to 2 `=`?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I suppose if you want to get explicit... The _real_ solution would be to run it through a parser and not through a regex test. even your modified pattern isn't going to tell you if it's real. **EDIT** BTW, OP only asked for a regex for "invalid Base64 characters", not "invalid base64 encoded values". ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie, you're right; the OP did say s/he was looking for a way to catch "invalid Base64 characters."  I mentioned the `=` issue because (a) you put it in your answer, and (b) an `=` was in the OP's original regex, so it was already on his/her mind.  (Upvote from me BTW)